# GCC __attribute__((used)) vs. linker file KEEP statement?

Tags: gcc, linker, attributes, ld

Using "Gnu Arm Embedded Toolchain", it seems that I need to have both this statement in my .c file:

```
__attribute__ ((section("section_name"),used))
```

and this statement in my .ld file:

```
KEEP(sectionname)
```

in order for that particular section to not get removed by linker garbage collection (`--gc-sections`).

Can anyone explain why or guide me to some documentation mentioning this?

Answer (score 1):

Both compiler and linker may remove functions which they consider to be unused (which usually means not reachable from `main`) so to preserve a function you need to inform both of the tools.

In theory compiler could automatically generate `KEEP` statements based on `used` attributes but this isn't done for historical reasons.

Comment: It seems that this doesn't apply to the situation where all objects in a file are not referenced. The file won't be linked even if `KEEP` is specified.